# How to install raphf on PHP 5.5.31 on MAC OS X el capitan?

Tags: pecl

I am trying to install raphf extension by following command.

```
sudo pecl install raphf-1.1.2
```

But its showing error as follows:

```
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/raphf/php_raphf.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/raphf
```

Has anyone had a similar experience? Please suggest me the steps I need to follow to install raphf on MAC OS X el capitan with PHP 5.5.31.

Thanks in advance.